# Simplifying Floor/Ceiling expressions

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I'm working with symbolic expressions using `Floor` and `Ceiling`, and I'm unable to get `Simplify` to evaluate them.  For instance, I would expect:

`Assuming[Element[n,Integers], Simplify[Ceiling[n/2] + Floor[n/2] == n]`

to result in `True`, but it doesn't. (`FullSimplify` doesn't work either.)

There is a work-around using `Resolve` given in the comment to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/213947/simplify-expression-to-floor).

However, I would like to somehow implement `Assuming` and `Simplify` to achieve the same result.  Is this possible?  It seems such a simple, obvious expression.

Edit: Here is a more complex comparison that I haven't been able to resolve even using the work-around linked above.

`Assuming[Element[n, Integers] && n > 0, Simplify[Ceiling[-(1/2) + 1/2 Sqrt[33 + 8 n]] == Floor[1/2 + 1/2 Sqrt[25 + 8 n]]]]`

Comment: Mathematica is not able to simplify such expression involving `Ceiling` or `Floor` automatically using `Simplify` or `FullSimplify` currently. Maybe in the future they will add such capabilities. For now you have to help Mathematica with such expression by code like @MarcoB posted in his answer.

Comment: Tim, I don't think what you look for is a simplification in the sense that Mathematica understands it, i.e. it does not follow from a pattern-based reworking of the expression, but instead it requires significant mathematical insight that is simply not built in. In your question, can you include how you would recognize that those two expressions are the same *by hand*? Then perhaps we could write an equivalent routine and include it an a transformation function in Simplify.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a brute-force approach and provide your own transformation function to handle that case:

```
Assuming[Element[n, Integers],
  Simplify[
    Ceiling[n/2] + Floor[n/2] == n,
    TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, ReplaceAll[Ceiling[a_] + Floor[a_] :> 2 a]}
  ]
]

(* Out: True *)
```

Comment: That makes sense, thanks.  However, I'm still wishing there were a way to deal with similar but more generalized floor/ceiling expressions using ```Simplify``` and ```Assuming```.

Comment: @TimWagner if you can show an example where this approach fails, then maybe we could try something different. As is, though, this solves the problem *as you asked it*, and unfortunately we can’t speculate further without an example.

Comment: I've edited the question to include a more complex comparison of the kind that I'm dealing with.  For this one, I couldn't even get [this workaround](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/213947/simplify-expression-to-floor) to handle it.